# Inserting data which doesnt match the column count value

Tags: php, mysql

Got a question about inserting data (10 columns) in a table which has 30 columns. I've set all the default values at NULL and inserting like this:

```
INSERT INTO `app_res_per_form` VALUES ('monkey', 'bizon', 'Option one,Option two', '2', '1,2,3,4', 'charmender', 'dodo', 'bird')
```

Doesnt work because I get a Column Count doesnt match Row Count. I can only presume that is because I don't have 30 values but only 10. Or is it something different?

The table I want to insert it into has 1 Primary Key ID int(11) and the rest is TEXT columns which has a Default of NULL.

Comment: Try to include column names in your query. `INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the columns you want to insert to

```
INSERT INTO `app_res_per_form` (<col1>,<col2>,...) VALUES (<val1>,<val2>,...)
```

If the primary key is an auto increment then you do not need to include that column. If it is not auto increment then you do.

Comment: Isn't it possible to auto fill that column with default value?

Answer (score 1):

You still have to pass NULL in the query for the columns and specify ALL columns in the query

Comment: Can't that be automatically done? I thought if you set the Default Values, the unspecified columns will get filled with the default value.

Comment: No, you still have to specify the column and pass in a null value